# Group Subtotal datatable na parte inferior

Tags: jquery, html5, datatable

Tenho um datatable com subtotal. [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/X5LB9/), porém esse subtotal fica na parte superior e preciso que apareça na parte inferior como subtotal.

Fazendo testes eu averiguei que ele gera o TR quando ele passa por essa linha de código

```
if (last !== group) {
    groupid++;
    $(rows).eq(i).before(
        '<tr class="group"><td>' + group + '</td></tr>'
    );
    last = group;
}
```

Como eu faria para que essa TR gere no final e não no começo de cada item?

Comment: Tente trocar o ".before" por ".after".

Comment: Eu tentei trocar, mas ele só pula uma linha e não resolve. Teria que ficar no final da lista.